# How can i create '.ipa' from XCode project?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've finished to write an application in XCode 12, and I want to publish it on App Store. How can I generate the '.ipa' file? Thank you!

Comment: "Archive" the application.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to point the target device to "Generic iOS Device" on the right of your name app on Xcode main view.

Then Product -> Archive.

I think that you want to publish the app, so there press "Validate app" for a first check of the app, then "Distribute App".

This in very very brief way. But publishing an app on the Apple store can be messy I think is better for you to read some comprehensive guide around.

This is a good one:

https://instabug.com/blog/how-to-submit-app-to-app-store/

Good luck